# Cross-referencing in postgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

I'm pretty new to postgreSQL, but I'm trying to figure out what the standard way is to cross-reference data. As an example, take the following code:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS order_items;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS products;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS orders;

CREATE TABLE products(
    product_id  SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name        TEXT,
    price       NUMERIC(5,2)
);

CREATE TABLE orders(
    order_id    SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    address     TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE order_items(
    product_id  INT REFERENCES products,
    order_id    INT REFERENCES orders,
    quantity    INT
);

INSERT INTO products(name, price) VALUES('socks', 4.98), ('shoes', 20.21), ('hats', 12.54);
INSERT INTO orders(address) VALUES('California'), ('New York');
INSERT INTO order_items VALUES(1, 1, 4);
INSERT INTO order_items VALUES(2, 1, 2);
INSERT INTO order_items VALUES(3, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO order_items VALUES(1, 2, 3);
INSERT INTO order_items VALUES(3, 2, 1);

SELECT order_id, product_id, quantity FROM order_items;
```

Which produces the following output:

```
 order_id | product_id | quantity
----------+------------+----------
        1 |          1 |        4
        1 |          2 |        2
        1 |          3 |        1
        2 |          1 |        3
        2 |          3 |        1
```

I want to know how to make this out of a single statement:

```
 orders.address | products.name | products.price | order_items.quantity
----------------+---------------+----------------+----------------------
 California     | socks         |           4.98 |                    4
 California     | shoes         |          20.21 |                    2
 California     | hats          |          12.54 |                    1
 New York       | socks         |           4.98 |                    3
 New York       | hats          |          12.54 |                    1
```

I think the solution may involve using `WITH` somehow, but I'm not sure.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a CTE to get the results. A query using aggregates and joins should get you want you want. Something like this:

```
select address, name, max(price) as price, sum(quantity) as quantity
from products p 
join order_items oi 
on p.product_id = oi.product_id
join orders o
on o.order_id = oi.order_id
group by address, name order by address;
```

[sample fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/967ac/1)

Comment: What is the advantage of using `max(price) as price, sum(quantity) as quantity` over `group by address, name, price, quantity`? We know it will be the sum of one value because we are joining them based on primary keys. Or is it a matter of taste?

Comment: Oh, I suppose you are correct.  I guess I was, incorrectly, assuming we would need to apply, at least, the sum of quantity.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done as simply as:

```
SELECT address, name, price, quantity 
FROM products p, order_items oi, orders o 
WHERE p.product_id = oi.product_id AND oi.order_id = o.order_id
ORDER BY address;
```